# How to skip numbering of Identity column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Recently I loaded my web app with a back up db. In the back up db the table didn't reached upto my present Identity numbering. I want to skip these numbers from my backup db identity seeding. please help, this is urgent!

Or

What will happen if I change the identity seed in the middle?

Comment: in the middle of what?

Comment: middle of numbering. The db is hosted and running.

Comment: Do you want to 1. reset the seed? 2. insert some values into an IDENTITY column? 3. something else?

Comment: table numbered 1,2,3,4 .Now I want to skip 5,6 and continue with 7,8,9...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('yourtablename', reseed, newvalue)
```

where `newvalue` is greater than max(currentvalue of identity column)

As per your comment *"table numbered 1,2,3,4 .Now I want to skip 5,6 and continue with 7,8,9"*

```
 DBCC CHECKIDENT ('mytablename', reseed, 7)
```